# Javascript to add menu to navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the below codes from w3schools.  How do I add more menu items in mySidenav with javascript dynamically?

CCS section:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

HTML body:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

How do I add object xxx to mySidenav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to use normal javascript for this, and nothing else!

Here's how it goes...

1. First off, define a variable that points to your sidebar using the `getElementById()` method of `document` object.

   ```
   var menu = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
   ```
2. Now, you can create a new element using `createElement()` method of `document` object.

   ```
   var newlink= document.createElement("a"); // In this case it's anchor element.
   ```
3. Now you can assign your object various properties, I won't tell how to do that here, you will have to search the [documentation](http://devdocs.io/dom-element/)
4. Finally after you've set the properties you want, you can simply append the object to the menu.

   ```
   menu.appendChild(newlink);
   ```

I hope this helped you! :D

Alice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var menu= document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    newItem = //create the new item here
 menu.insertBefore(newItem, menu.childNodes[0]);
```

Comment: You should add, that this is not vanilla solution, but it requires jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and seems to work:

```
var nav=document.getElementById("mySidenav");
var node = document.createElement("a");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("newlink");
node.appendChild(textnode);
node.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');
nav.appendChild(node);
```