# How do you make an updatable NavBar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a Navbar for my website, but I would like to be able to update all of them across my website by editing some code in JS. Please note that I am extremely bad at JS, and I admit that it may not be possible with JavaScript. Here is the code for the HTML.

```css
nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  height: min-content;
  position: fixed;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

nav img {
  height: 47px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: -apple-system;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

nav .nohover:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <li><img src="image" class="navimg"></li>
  <li><a href="website1">website1</a></li>
  <li><a href="webite2">website2</a></li>
  <li><a href="website3">website3</a></li>
</nav>
```

The information will be very helpful. If you know how to do it, please tell me.

Comment: What do you want to update? Color? background color? Text?

Comment: I would like to be able to update the amount of links and the data on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532021/javascript-to-add-menu-to-navbar

Comment: @GnomeDev  You can update everything using JS and only JS can be used to update. Browser only reads JS. You can create the entire nav div using JS without using html .I will update the code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the HTML part and add the following code in your js file . All you have to do is to edit the menuArray. Just populate as much as you want.

```js
var menuArray = ['website1', 'website2', 'website3']

var navdiv = document.createElement("div");
navdiv.setAttribute('class', 'container')
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
menuArray.forEach((ele) => {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = ele
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
navdiv.appendChild(ul)
document.body.prepend(navdiv);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful!

Comment: Glad I can help you. Help others whenever you get chances.

Comment: The only thing wrong with it is that I can't get it to do it at the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

To me it is not very clear what you want, but if you want to change the link you can use this. I also gave the `a` tags a class so I can call them with the JQuery code!

**EDIT:**
We are a community who helps you solve your coding problems, not write the entire code for you. So please keep that in mind for your next question on StackOverflow.

**EDIT 2:** I kept the `css` code out because it is irrelevant.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link1').parent().html('<a class="link1" href="changed1">changed1</a>');
    $('.link2').parent().html('<a class="link2" href="changed2">changed2</a>');
    $('.link3').parent().html('<a class="link3" href="changed3">changed3</a>');
    // if you want to add a new item to the end
    $('li:last').append('<li><a class="link4" href="changed4">changed4</a></li>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="container">
      <li><img  src="image" class="navimg"></li>
      <li><a class="link1" href="website1">website1</a></li>
      <li><a class="link2" href="webite2">website2</a></li>
      <li><a class="link3" href="website3">website3</a></li>
</nav>
```